# How to return multiple generic error types in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, error-handling, union-types

I am trying to return errors of multiple types from a method, one error being generic.

I'd like not to use the `Box<dyn Error>` trick, mostly to learn how to achieve what I want to implement here.

The get function retrieves a value from the DB (which can fail with a `rusqlite::Error`), and then parses the value with `from_str`, which is defined on the generic return type of get.

```
enum GetError<T: std::str::FromStr> {
  Error1(T::Err),
  Error2(rusqlite::Error)
}

impl<T: std::str::FromStr> From<T::Err> for GetError<T> {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  fn from(value: T) -> Self {
    GetError::Error1(value)
  }
}

impl<T: std::str::FromStr> From<rusqlite::Error> for GetError<T> {
  fn from(value: rusqlite::Error) -> Self {
    GetError::Error2(value)
  }
}

pub fn get<T>(&self, key: &str) -> Result<T, GetError<T>>
  where
    T: std::str::FromStr,
    {
      match self.connection.query_row("SELECT value FROM key_values WHERE key = ?1", params![key], |row| { row.get::<usize, String>(0) }) {
        Err(error) => Err(GetError::Error2(error)),
        Ok(value) => T::from_str(&value).or_else(|e| GetError::Error1(e))
    }
}
```

It's telling me that there is already an implementation of the trait `From` defined in `std::convert`.

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<storage::permanent_key_value_store::GetError<_>>` for type `storage::permanent_key_value_store::GetError<_>`
  --> src/storage/permanent_key_value_store.rs:13:1
   |
13 | impl<T: std::str::FromStr> From<T::Err> for GetError<T> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
           - impl<T> std::convert::From<T> for T;
```

Is there a way to return a generic error `GetError` that could stand for a `rusqlite::Error` or any `FromStr::Err`?

---

Thank you so much!

Now the code boils down to (using ?):

```
pub enum GetError<T: std::str::FromStr> {
  Error1(T::Err),
  Error2(rusqlite::Error)
}

impl<T: std::str::FromStr> From<rusqlite::Error> for GetError<T> {
  fn from(value: rusqlite::Error) -> Self {
    GetError::Error2(value)
  }
}

pub fn get<T>(&self, key: &str) -> Result<T, GetError<T>>
  where
    T: std::str::FromStr,
    {
      let value = self.connection.query_row(
        "SELECT value FROM key_values WHERE key = ?1", 
        params![key], 
        |row| { row.get::<usize, String>(0) }
      )?;
      T::from_str(&value).map_err(GetError::Error1)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that one can put whatever they want in their `FromStr`'s associated type `Err`, for example:

```rust
struct Foo;
impl std::str::FromStr for Foo {
    type Err = GetError<Foo>;
    
    // ...
}
```

And then the `From` impl you wrote for `GetError<Foo>` will collide with the empty, provided-by-std `impl<T> From<T> for T` impl.

You can avoid that by getting rid of this `From` impl and constructing the error manually:

```rust
enum GetError<T: std::str::FromStr> {
    Error1(T::Err),
    Error2(rusqlite::Error),
}

impl<T: std::str::FromStr> From<rusqlite::Error> for GetError<T> {
    fn from(value: rusqlite::Error) -> Self {
        GetError::Error2(value)
    }
}

pub fn get<T>(&self, key: &str) -> Result<T, GetError<T>>
where
    T: std::str::FromStr,
{
    match self.connection.query_row(
        "SELECT value FROM key_values WHERE key = ?1",
        params![key],
        |row| row.get::<usize, String>(0),
    ) {
        Err(error) => Err(GetError::Error2(error)),
        Ok(value) => T::from_str(&value).map_err(|e| GetError::Error1(e)),
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It did not occur to me that returning directly an enum value from GetError freed me from the requirement to implement the From trait! The `or_else` was also misused, thanks for correcting it to `map_err`! 